# How to open Chrome's Internal Pages from terminal

Tags: terminal, google-chrome

I want to open chrome's internal pages like `chrome://version` via terminal. I know I can use the [`open`](https://superuser.com/a/1148415/913193) command to open any URL, but how to open the internal pages?

I tried `open -a Google\ Chrome "chrome://version"`, but It thinks `chrome:` is some folder and gives me this error

> `The file /Users/devuser/chrome:/version does not exist.`

Comment: First, are those pages static HTML? Something tells me probably not. Second, where exactly are these pages located? Likely (if they exist at all) inside the Chrome.app package, or perhaps in the Chrome profile location, which will require a small amount of investigating on your part.

Comment: Chrome allows you to view the source HTML of that page, so you should be able find its HTML file by searching for some of its contents.

Comment: I tried `grep` some keywords but couldn't find anything in the application folder. It looks like they are created on runtime.

Comment: Are you open to use `osascript` command instead? I don't think its possible to use `open` since it seems attempt to process the link first before passing it to chrome

Comment: This thread might put you on the right path

https://superuser.com/questions/836769/how-can-i-open-a-non-http-url-chrome-extension-in-google-chrome-from-the-termi

Comment: The thread is what I need. Thanks @Volsk